# MarkupInterface interoperability with other PHP frameworks

Tags: 8

### Situation in Drupal 8

Drupal 8 introduces a few classes and interfaces for safe markup:

- `Drupal\Component\Render\MarkupInterface`
- `Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup`
- `Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup`

The purpose is

- to mark a string as being safe for use in html, without further sanitization.
- to have the string be lazy-evaluated.

The problem seems to be that all of these are specific to Drupal.

### Use case

I am designing an API I want to publish as a composer package, that should be used and implemented within Drupal 8 but also work outside of it. It should not depend on anything within Drupal.

There are interfaces that can return string labels, or arrays of such labels (e.g. to act as option labels in a select element).

Implementations within Drupal will want to use the `t()` function, which returns `TranslatableMarkup` objects. But the interface or the calling code know nothing about Drupal's `TranslatableMarkup` or `MarkupInterface`.

### Solutions considered so far

One option would be to require all implementations to return plain strings, which they can do via `(string)` cast, or by calling the `__toString()` method. This would work but it feels unnatural.

Another option would be to introduce a custom `TranslatableString` object which my own API can understand. This would replace a Drupalism with a my-own-ism, and also feel clumsy for implementations within D8.

Another option would be to allow the interface to return arbitrary values and later attempt to convert them to strings using either a flexible adapter layer, or attempting to call the __toString() function. This would make it harder to require a specific return type, and detect if an implementation returns "illegal" values.

### Question

Have there been any attempts to make a "bridge" between Drupal's `MarkupInterface` (EDIT: And `TranslatableMarkup`) and the larger PHP ecosystem?

---

### Ongoing discussion

There are some comments below which point to interesting directions.

I'd say the main question is still open: How can we bridge the Drupal-specific classes and interfaces to the outside world? Are there Drupal-agnostic versions of these classes and interfaces?

Comment: Another option is for your API package to include implementation-specific classes. One for Drupal, one for Wordpress, one for whatever, and a fallback class for posting raw data in whatever way is appropriate for the API (presumably string). The Drupal one can specifically take a `MarkupInterface` and cast/etc before passing the result to a parent implementation. If you definitely don't want any environment-specific code in the package, option 1 sounds fine to me. If the API needs a string to work, it shouldn't have to worry about where that string came from; the caller should do the worrying

Comment: @Clive "the caller should do the worrying" - in this case the API (= my package) would be the caller. The API publishes an interface, a Drupal module implements it, then the API contains other classes that get instances of that interface injected.

Comment: @Clive "implementation-specific classes" - I would have to introduce ecosystem-specific interfaces, not just classes, because the return type is part of the interface contract. And more than one of them, for different purposes. In fact I might still do this, but it would lead to further clutter of interfaces. I already have plenty of them..

Comment: @Clive "option 1 sounds fine to me. If the API needs a string to work, it shouldn't have to worry about where that string came from" - one flaw of Drupal's t() is that it needs services and context variables (current language) to work. To avoid getting those services from global `\Drupal::service()`, these services would have to be injected into the implementation that constructs the translatable string object. If I were to create my own TranslatableString or TranslatableMarkup class, it would be a pure value object unable to translate itself.

Comment: I ran out of characters before I could say the "implementation-specific" idea wasn't an ideal one :) For the last point, why not make the implementations a plugin? The base class can have the necessary services, implementations can be slim

Comment: @Clive "For the last point, why not make the implementations a plugin? The base class can have the necessary services, implementations can be slim" - This only solves the problem if the plugin creation is black-boxed away to the plugin system. I see some limitations here to the way I intend to use this, but I will see how it fits together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR

*(this summarizes conclusions from the comments below)*

The `MarkupInterface` is available on packagist as part of the [`drupal/core-render`](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-render) package, which provides all the classes from `Drupal\Component\Render\*` without any heavy dependencies (only [`drupal/core-util`](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-util)). It does *not* give you `TranslatableMarkup`, though.

If you let your package depend on `drupal/core-render`, you can use `MarkupInterface` as a return type.

Implementations within Drupal modules, which call `t()` and return a `TranslatableMarkup` object, would satisfy the return type from the interface.

Implementations outside of Drupal would instead return `FormattableMarkup`, or `HtmlEscapedText`, or a custom implementation of `MarkupInterface`. Or something else, if the interface allows alternative return types (e.g. native string).

You need to decide if you accept this dependency, or do something else instead.

### Original (longer) answer

The ultimate goal of having the two names spaces in Drupal is

- `Drupal\Component` is for classes that do not need a bootstrapped kernel.  In other words, these do not need a running Drupal system. These classes may depend on other classes outside `Drupal\Component` (eg, `Symfony`) or other classes in `Drupal\Component`, but not `Drupal\Core`
- `Drupal\Core` is for classes that require a bootstrapped kernel.  These full from `Drupal\Core`, `Drupal\Component`, and elsewhere.

Take date/time objects.

- `DrupalDateTime` is in `Drupal\Core` because leverages the translation service.
- `DateTimePlus is in`Drupal\Component`because it adds some enhancements to the native`\DateTime` class.

So, in theory, `Drupal\Component` can be used in anything. That said, the `composer.json` files for each component may not be accurate for dependencies and minimum PHP version.

In your case, `MarkupInterface` and `FormattableMarkup` should be able to be used outside of Drupal. `TranslatableMarkup` relies on the Drupal translation system, which needs a booted kernel to operate.

`TranslatableMarkup` essentially just extends `FormattableMarkup`, and acts a bridge to the string translation service. So, that on its own doesn't buy you much unless you need everything that surrounds translation (language management, the UI, etc).

All of that said, I am not sure how much you will really gain from this. Ignoring the translation parts, `FormattableMarkup` is a component, but they are really best used as part of the rendering service, which is part of core.  For the purposes of making your own API, I would start with seeing if you can just leverage `FormattableMarkup` on its own.

Comment: "So, in theory, Drupal\Component can be used in anything." - If I want to publish an interface where MarkupInterface is advertised as a return type, then the package would have to depend on drupal/core, or a subset of that (e.g the render component). Is this even possible? And if so, how many unnecessary dependencies would this bring about?

Comment: @donquixote I have never done this, but I think all of the components are split out on Packagist in the `drupal/core-*` requirements.  Try `composer require drupal/core-render` and see what you get.

Comment: Indeed, it exists! https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-render. It has a cyclic dependency with https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-utility, but no further dependencies. Good to know!

Comment: The core-render package looks surprisingly slim, without any baggage from the actual render system. I am still not sure if I want to depend on it in a 3rd party package, but it is much better than I thought.

Comment: I edited the answer. I was not aware my edit would be accepted immediately, I thought you would have to approve first. Please have a look if you agree!

Comment: I am accepting this until something better comes along :)